# Тестирование правильности UUID

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

Столкнулся с проблемой написания теста контроллера который передает UUID пользователя в неправильном формате. Тест на проверку существования пользователя с введенным UUID написал успешно (приложу ниже), а вот исключение на обработку неправильного формата UUID придумать не могу.

Контроллер пользователя

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public UserReadDTO getUser (@PathVariable UUID id) {
        return userService.getUser(id);
    }
}
```

Тест проверки существования пользователя

```
 @Test
public void testGetUserWrongId() throws Exception {
    UUID wrongId = UUID.randomUUID();

    EntityNotFoundException exception = new EntityNotFoundException(User.class, wrongId);
    Mockito.when(userService.getUser(wrongId)).thenThrow(exception);

    String resultJson = mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/users/{id}", wrongId))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

    Assert.assertTrue(resultJson.contains(exception.getMessage()));
}
```

Исключение

```
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public EntityNotFoundException(Class entityClass, UUID id){
        super(String.format("Entity %s with id=%s is not found", entityClass.getSimpleName(), id));
    }
}
```

**То что придумал сам по этой теме**

Тест проверки правильности UUID

```
 @Test
public void testGetWrongUUID() throws Exception {
    String wrongId = "123";

    WrongUuidException exception = new WrongUuidException(wrongId);

    String resultJson = mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/users/{id}", wrongId))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

    Assert.assertTrue(resultJson.contains(exception.getMessage()));
}
```

Исключение

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class WrongUuidException extends RuntimeException {
    public WrongUuidException(String id) {
        super(String.format("Correlation ID is not a valid UUID: %s" , id));
    }
}
```

Сообщение об ошибке:

```
{"status":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","exceptionClass":"org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException","message":"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.UUID'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 123"}
```

А должна быть ошибка `400 Bad request`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041051/how-to-judge-a-string-is-uuid-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добро пожаловать на русский Stackoverflow!

Spring framework выполняет валидацию на корректность UUID и бросает `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 123`, который потом заворачивается в `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`.

В вашем случае можно реализовать свою проверку UUID, изменив входящий тип на `String`:

```
public UserReadDTO getUser(@PathVariable String id) {
   try {
       return userService.getUser(UUID.fromString(id));
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException exc) {
       throw new WrongUuidException(id); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Тесты поднимаются и все корректно обрабатывается.